# avr-g++.exe: error: device-specs/specs-avr2: No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, path, g++

I'm trying to install Marlin on an Ender 3. But Arduino IDE is giving me this error:

```
C:\Users\Michael.Heredia\Downloads\Marlin-2.0.x\Marlin-2.0.x\Marlin\src\lcd\dogm\HAL_LCD_class_defines.h: In member function 'void U8GLIB_SSD1309_128X64_HAL::init(pin_t, pin_t, pin_t)': C:\Users\Michael.Heredia\Downloads\Marlin-2.0.x\Marlin-2.0.x\Marlin\src\lcd\dogm\HAL_LCD_class_defines.h:134:5: error: 'init' is not a member of 'U8GLIB'
 U8GLIB::init(&u8g_dev_ssd1309_hw_spi, (uint8_t)cs, (uint8_t)a0, (uint8_t)reset);
```

I've decided to try `auto build Marlin` on VSCode but cannot get past this error:

```
avr-g++.exe: error: device-specs/specs-avr2: No such file or directory
```

I've looked across many forums and the most common issue seems to be adding or deleting something in the path. Judging by the fact that it is a `No such file or directory error`, I need to add something to the path, but all the solutions I've found seem to have different things, and none of them seem to explain where I find the directory to add to the path.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Close VSC and go to C:\Users\yourname and delete the .platformio folder.
Restart VS Code and you should get a fresh install of Platformio.
This should get you going.